# SSRS Portal Menus missing on remote node

Tags: ssrs

New security maybe? The Data Source added to the root is not seen on the remote node but the Reports folder is and if I create a Data Source in the Reports folder I can then see them on the remote node. I also have all the menus on the remote node when the Reports folder is selected. ???

---

The portal opens and works on the SSRS server but on a remote server the options are missing. No "New" menu, so I can't add a folder or Data Source.

Local:

[image: Local]

Remote:

[image: Remote]

Not currently on a domain but the same local Admin account is used on all servers and was used for the install and setup. At first I also could not look at Security in the Site settings but they are now there after adding the local account to the security settings but the menu options are still not there. The old system with SQL 2012 SSRS has all the options on the local or remote web page.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That potentially could be down to the OS as much as SSRS. The local accounts may have different SID's, and different passwords, the servers may belong to different workgroups...

For the local SIDS you could check via PowerShell (replace the word Guest with the name of the account):

```
 Get-LocalUser -Name Guest | SELECT SID
```

Or from the command line (replace the word Guest with the name of the account):

```
 wmic useraccount  where name='Guest' get sid
```

If the servers were all on the same domain, then I wouldn't expect an issue. You could also try signing in with Destination Server Name\LoginName to see if that makes any difference... i.e. SRV1\MyLoginName

Comment: All are VMs and all were setup from the same template with the same local accounts and passwords and the default Workgroup. 

Would that be singing into the web page? I did not see a way to do that. It just defaults to the same local Admin account name in the top right of the page. 

And they have the same SID.

Comment: Not sure if I should setup a new question but I can't seem to match the Data Source used in the reports. Added in the same way as the existing SSRS but the report will not use it.